# Office 2013 backstage browse button displaying an incorrect directory

Tags: microsoft-office-2013

Anyone know where the Office 2013 file>save as>computer>browse button is getting its path from?

We have an odd problem on some machines running Office 2013.

The problem is that when the users open or save documents in office they click on file > Save As > computer > browse to select the directory but office then displays a window showing "opening \oldserver\documentsdir\" which searches and times out or the user clicks on another button. I want it to open the users document directory, or at least something which exists and not its current value.

I've done all the obvious things. The default directory paths in office options are pointing to to the new server. I've searched the registry for references to \oldserver. I've grepped the users entire profiles searching for \oldserver, I've also grepped \programdata - and found nothing referencing \oldserver. (well I did find some things and changed them)

I cannot find a single reference to this directory but it continues to appear each time we browse.

Disabling backstage isn't really an option (tried that) as, even if you do disable it, the backstage screen is still displayed in some places when you go to save or open and so the browse button is there.